# How do I count number of columns that differ between rows with same ID?

Tags: sql, aginity

Working with table containing 5 columns and many rows. Only column to note is Order_number. I need to be able to calculate the percent change between rows that have the same order_number, using first row as a reference.

Example: Say we have four rows with the same order_id, using the earliest time as a reference, we can see that one row has one column difference and one that has two columns different. The newly created column calculates the percent difference.

Before:

```
Order_number | color | price | location | time
```

---

```
5            |  blue |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:30
5            |  red  |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49
5            | green |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49
5            |  blue |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49
```

After:

```
Order_number | color | price | location | time  | percent_change
```

---

```
5            |  blue |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:30 | 0
5            |  red  |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49 | 40
5            | green |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49 | 60
5            |  blue |  2.99 |   Ohio   | 11:49 | 20
```

Comment: you have to do the comparison on a field by field basis and add the differences or equals up

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: A few things that might add clarity to the question: what are those 10 columns? Are their data-types same too in order to make a comparison? Should the comparisons be made within the row or within a _set_ of rows belonging to the `order_id`?

Comment: "using the first row as a reference" - How do you know which one is the "first"?

Comment: I use over( partition by order_number)
They will already be in order by order_number.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support window functions. Are you using SQL-Server? Please use correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
select count( distinct * ) from table
```

Comment: This would eliminate the duplicates but I wish to add a column that analyzes them, even if they are same. Rows that are duplicate would have 0% percent difference.